# Averaging and decreasing the array (vector) C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, boost, stl

I've got an array (actually `std::vector`) size ~ 7k elements. 
If you draw this data, there will be a diagram of the combustion of the fuel. But I want to minimize this vector from 7k elements to 721 (every 0.5 degree) elements or ~ 1200 (every 0.3 degree). Of course I want save diagram the same. How can I do it?
Now I am getting every 9 element from big vector to new and cutting other evenly from front and back of vector to get 721 size.

```
QVector <double> newVMTVector;
for(QVector <double>::iterator itv = oldVmtDataVector.begin(); itv < oldVmtDataVector.end() - 9; itv+=9){
    newVMTVector.push_back(*itv);
}
auto useless = newVMTVector.size() - 721;
if(useless%2 == 0){
    newVMTVector.erase(newVMTVector.begin(), newVMTVector.begin() + useless/2);
    newVMTVector.erase(newVMTVector.end() - useless/2, newVMTVector.end());
}
else{
    newVMTVector.erase(newVMTVector.begin(), newVMTVector.begin() + useless/2+1);
    newVMTVector.erase(newVMTVector.end() - useless/2, newVMTVector.end());
}
newVMTVector.squeeze();
oldVmtDataVector.clear();
oldVmtDataVector = newVMTVector;
```

I can swear there is an algorithm that averages and reduces the array.

Comment: What is it that your current code is failing to do?

Comment: you could try with `std::transform` applying a custom lambda to average numbers out.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.   Are you saying that you have a vector of some type which contains information representing a diagram?   And do you want to reduce the number of elements of the vector in some way, in order to still be able to draw the same diagram at a lower resolution?

Comment: Are these values distributed evenly with respect to the degrees? I mean do you know that every 9th value means 0.5 degree change?

Comment: Current code I think works normal, but I think there is much better solution.

Comment: @dau_sama Can you please show me how you see it should be done

Comment: Better in terms of what? Performance? Accuracy of the diagram?

Comment: @KjMag I know that ~7k points it's 360 degrees. I want to display it every 0.5 degree it means that i should to have vector with 721 values. And i'am doing small vector with that code.

Comment: @KjMag Accuracy, because when i am taking every 9 element (at all 721) I'am throwing out 7k-721 of elements and losing in accuracy.

Comment: No, that doesn't mean that. It would mean that if you knew that your vector contains exactly 7200 points and every point in that vector corresponds to 0.05 deg. You shouldn't do it the way you do it now unless you have certainty that the points are evenly distributed every 0.05 deg.

Comment: "~7k" -- How many exactly? 7200? 7201? | I see this tagged as "stl" and "boost', yet there's a vector class from Qt... why? | Why do you need to erase things from a vector you just populated? | Interpolation might help.

Comment: @KjMag I don't how much point's i'm getting every time. But I know that I know that every point in that vector corresponds to 360/%size_of_array% deg. They are evenly distributed

Comment: @DanMašek Because I think that's it's answer it that libraries. I don't know how to use interpolation in that case.

Comment: Ok, it's starting to be clear then. And are you interested in getting these points exactly every 0.5 or 0.3 degree, or do you just want to make diagram smaller, e.g. every 0.23 degree instead of 0.023 so that it has 10 times less points?

Comment: @KjMag yes, or as in question 721 elements to draw instead of 7k

Comment: Ok, but to which part of my question does your 'yes' refer to? Do you want points exactly e.g. every 0.5 degree or you don't care whether they are every 0.5, 0.23, 0734 or whatever as long as you may reduce the size of the vector?

Comment: @KjMag every 0.5 degree. I think it's about interpolation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is an interpolation. There are many libraries providing many types of interpolation. This one is very lightweight and easy to setup and run:

http://kluge.in-chemnitz.de/opensource/spline/

All you need to do is create the second vector that contains the X values, pass both vectors to generate spline, and generate interpolated results every 0.5 degrees or whatever:

```
std::vector<double> Y; // Y is your current vector of fuel combustion values with ~7k elements
std::vector<double> X;
X.reserve(Y.size());

double step_x = 360 / (double)Y.size();
for (int i = 0; i < X.size(); ++i)
    X[i] = i*step_x;

tk::spline s;
s.set_points(X, Y);
double interpolation_step = 0.5;

std::vector<double> interpolated_results;
interpolated_results.reserve(std::ceil(360/interpolation_step) + 1);
for (double i = 0.0, int j = 0; i <= 360; i += interpolation_step, ++j) // <= in order to obtain range <0;360>
    interpolated_results[j] = s(i);

if (fmod(360, interpolation_step) != 0.0) // for steps that don't divide 360 evenly, e.g. 0.7 deg, we need to close the range
    interpolated_results.back() = s(360);

// now interpolated_results contain values every 0.5 degrees
```

This should give you and idea how to use this kind of libraries. If you need some other interpolation type, just find the one that suits your needs. The usage should be similar.

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand it you want to pick the elements [0, k, 2k, 3k ... ] where n is 10 or n is 6.

Here's a simple take:

```
template <typename It>
It strided_inplace_reduce(It it, It const last, size_t stride) {
    It out = it;
    if (stride < 1) return last;

    while (it < last)
    {
        *out++ = *it;
        std::advance(it, stride);
    }

    return out;
}
```

Generalizing a bit for non-random-access iterators:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eea57adc011adb2c)</kbd>**

```
#include <iterator>

namespace detail {
    // version for random access iterators
    template <typename It>
    It strided_inplace_reduce(It it, It const last, size_t stride, std::random_access_iterator_tag) {
        It out = it;
        if (stride < 1) return last;

        while (it < last)
        {
            *out++ = *it;
            std::advance(it, stride);
        }

        return out;
    }

    // other iterator categories
    template <typename It>
    It strided_inplace_reduce(It it, It const last, size_t stride, ...) {
        It out = it;
        if (stride < 1) return last;

        while (it != last) {
            *out++ = *it;
            for (size_t n = stride; n && it != last; --n)
            {
                it = std::next(it);
            }
        }

        return out;
    }
}

template <typename Range>
auto strided_inplace_reduce(Range& range, size_t stride) {
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;

    using It = decltype(begin(range));
    It it = begin(range), last = end(range);

    return detail::strided_inplace_reduce(it, last, stride, typename std::iterator_traits<It>::iterator_category{});
}

#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    {
        std::vector<int> v { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
        v.erase(strided_inplace_reduce(v, 2), v.end());

        std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout << "\nv: ", " "));
    }
    {
        std::list<int> l { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
        l.erase(strided_inplace_reduce(l, 4), l.end());

        std::copy(l.begin(), l.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout << "\nl: ", " "));
    }
}
```

Prints

```
v: 1 3 5 7 9 
l: 1 5 9
```

Comment: To be honest, to me it looks more like a signal processing problem -- resampling a signal from one uniform rate to another (with the rates fairly arbitrary, as the number of input samples seems unknown). I'd be looking for a C++ equivalent of something like scipy or Matlab resample.

Comment: BTW, in the example with `std::list` -- when stride is 4, shouldn't it be elements at positions 0, 4 and 8? i.e. `1 5 9` rather than `1 6`? The live sample prints the right result, so I guess you just forgot to update the result in the answer.

Comment: @DanMašek possibly, it's not what he describes though. And yes, the output was a copy paste issue (as you can see if you follow the live link)